# GCM Server knowing of successful delivery

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

As far I as know, upon successful posting a notification to GCM Server, it will return a status code of 200 and a response as such id=1:2342.

However, according to their [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html), this does not guarantee successful delivery to the device. Just a successful status of delivering the notification to the GCM server.

So my question is, is there a way for me to know that the notification has been sent to the phone successfully? Is there a Delivery Notification returned by GCM to my side upon successful delivery? If not, does any of you guys have any ideas on keeping track of those?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCM does not notify your server when the message is sent to the phone.

If you require that functionality, you'll have to implement it yourself. You can attach a message identifier field to the GCM message. When the message arrives to the phone, your app will send that message identifier back to your server (using an HTTP request), to acknowledge that it received the message.

Comment: I see. So basically I need to trigger the Delivery Notification myself from the application. Much thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to send that message back to my server regardless of whether the user chooses to activate the message?

Comment: @NielsBrinch Yes it is. Since on Android you are responsible to writing the code that displays the notification to the user, you can send the ack message to your server before displaying the notification, so it doesn't matter if the user click on the notification or not.